# How to use a web-scraping data with mysql? (python 2.7)

Tags: python, database, mysql-python, create-table, insert-into

I have got the next webscraping code :

```js
name = soup.find('span', { "class" : "name"})
print name
```

I need this value, what i am printing.

How can I use it this "name" in mysqldb? I want to create a database with the value name.

I tried this, but it isnt work:

```js
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='1234',
    db='database')
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """ 
   "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ name+ " name VARCHAR(120) (
  `Megnevezes` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ev1` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ev2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ev3` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ev4` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ev5` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"""
cursor.execute(query)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()

connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='1234',
    db='database')
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """ load data local infile 'C:/Python27/output.csv' 
into table "name"
character set latin1
fields terminated by ';'
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n'
ignore 1 lines;
"""
cursor.execute(query)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Comment: you are creating a Table, which is different as how to create a database

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a database with the value name.

You are running the command to create a `Table` not a `Database`. To do so run the following command:

```
CREATE DATABASE name;
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660417/how-to-create-a-mysql-database-with-sql-commands) question regarding the creation of databases (although it is closed as too broad).